# How to connect mini dv camcorder to my 2013 MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, video, imovie, accessories, video-adapter

I am needing to connect my camcorder, which uses mini dv tapes, to my mac so I can transfer the video to an electronic file, but the only output on the camcorder is an A/v and i'm not sure what connections to use.

I need to know what connectors will connect from a/v to my macbook air.

Answer (score 1):

Apple sells a Thunderbolt to Firewire adapter. And you would need a FW800 to 4 pin FW400 to connect to your DV camera. Then I think iMovie will be able to handle your DV camcorder.

Answer (score 0):

you can buy a av to mini usb on amazon or over google shopper from around £8 so I'm sure you will be able to transfer the data that way.